# ArrayList Issue in Reducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I'm performing some calculations in reducer and trying to load the data into an ArrayList. When I perform a get operation on ArrayList at later point of code, all objects in ArrayList have same value.

```
public ArrayList<some_class> temp = new ArrayList<some_class>();
//This is global variable

@Override
public void reduce(Key_class key, Iterator<some_class> values,
        OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
                throws IOException {
    if(this.output==null){
        this.output=output;
    }

    while(values.hasNext())
    {
                    //if i print here
                    //and do the following values.next().val1
                    //I'm getting the right result
        temp.add(values.next());
    }

    System.out.println(temp.get(0).val1);//Wrong result
}
```

I'm getting output as below:
12/10/2012 10:13
12/10/2012 10:13

Actual output should be :
12/10/2012 09:10
12/10/2012 10:13

Appreciate your help. Thanks!!!

Comment: Well you're always printing out the *first* element of `temp`... did you really mean to?

Comment: that was just for testing purpose, but it's value is supposed to be 12/10/2012 09:10 instead i get 12/10/2012 10:13

Comment: Are you sure your Reducer instance is not reused? Because using a field instead of a local variable to hold your temp values is a bit of a code smell for such a class (though I'm not familiar with Hadoop). Why do you need a (public) field? Scope and visibility should be as limited as possible (objects are supposed to _encapsulate_).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Patricia Shanahan has already noted, the objects are being re-used - the underlying contents of the object is being updated (but all the child objects etc are also being reused, well that depends on your readFields / write methods).

You can get around this my making copies of the objects before adding them to the ArrayList:

```
@Override
public void reduce(Key_class key, Iterator<some_class> values,
    OutputCollector<Text, Text> output, Reporter reporter)
            throws IOException {
  if(this.output==null){
    this.output=output;
  }

  // you should out the arraylist to avoid unexpected behaviour and OOME
  temp.clear();

  while(values.hasNext())
  {
    // you'll need a copy of the configuration - conf
    temp.add(
        ReflectionUtils.copy(conf, values.next(), new some_class()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

What is the implementation of values? One cause of the symptoms would be if values.mext() always returns a reference to the same object, but changes the value of that object to match the next item in the iteration. If you do not have access to its source code, you could test for this condition by printing the System.identityHashCode() for the values.next() result inside the loop.

If that is what is going on, you either need to fix the implementation of the Iterator to return a different object each time, or you need to clone the object before adding to the ArrayList.

Comment: values.next() is returning different objects, but once i load into ArrayList and use it in subsequent calculations...the objects in arraylist have same objects.

Comment: Patricia is correct here.  The iterator implementation reuses the same writable object with different values as an optimization.  You will have to create and store a new object if you want unique values in your array.